# $\lambda$-pure morphisms in $\lambda$-accessible categories are monos, unclear proof

Tags: category-theory, morphism, monomorphisms, accessible-categories

This is [Proposition 2.29](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA86) from the book *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories* by Jiří Adámek and Jiří Rosický.

[image]

Above is a proof that $\lambda$-pure morphisms in $\lambda$-accessible categories are monos. It is unclear to me why do we create new $h$ instead of taking $\bar{v}$ in the line -4 and why such a $h$ exists in the canonical diagram of $B$ by the displayed line -5th?

Comment: I get a link to a Czech page containing a link to an .xps file, whatever that is. It's best to embed your images directly in the post.

Comment: Can you provide me with a link to an upload site for math.stackexchange? Thank you.

Comment: By clicking on the landscape image in the edit mode, you can upload, drag and drop, or copy and paste an image from your computer or from elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: I've corrected the above link to point to the page with jpg.

Comment: I inserted the image in your question.

Comment: I will mention that there is a [proposal onn meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/29791#29791) suggesting creation of tags (accessible-categories) and (locally-presentable-categories). (This is also a partial answer to your question on meta - now deleted - which asked among other things where to post proposals for new tags.) Feel free to ping me either here [or in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/2/12) after you've seen this - since the comment is about creating new tags and unrelated to the question, I can delete it after that.

Comment: That is nice that this tag is going to be added. Generally how do I request correctly  for new (other) tags?

Comment: @user122424 Whether or not the tag is going to be added depends on the outcome of that discussion on meta. (So if you have some arguments why those tags might be useful, you could comment there - or at least upvote the suggestion.) Re: *How to I request for new tags?* Well, the linked post is an example - you can post suggestions of new tags on meta. But perhaps it's better to discuss this in more detail [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/2/15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the first part of the proof is to find a morphism of $\lambda$-presentable objects which coequalizes $p'$ and $q'$ to which to apply the assumption of purity on $f$. There is no reason why $\bar fp'$ should equal $\bar f q'$, so it would be useless to apply purity before constructing $h$. That said, the reason $h$ exists is that the canonical diagram of $B$ is filtered. We have parallel maps $\bar f p'$ and $\bar f q'$ in that diagram, and so there must exist a map $h$ in the diagram coequalizing them.

Comment: OK. Why do we need **coequalizing** $\bar f p'$ and $\bar f q'$ rather than just precomposing them with $h$ and making them equal by this precomposition?

Comment: The map $h\bar{f}$ coequalizes $p'$ and $q'$, i.e. the equation
$(h\bar{f})p' = (h\bar{f})q'$holds.

Comment: Why such an coequalizer exits ? I know, however, that the diagram is filtetred.

Comment: @user122424 What definition of filtered do you favor? This follows either instantly or quickly from any of them. To be clear, this isn't a coequalizer in the sense of a colimit, it's just an arbitrary cocone over the diagram given by two parallel arrows.

Comment: That's actually point of my question. When you say "coequalizer" then I automatically mean colimit of two parallel arrows.

Comment: @user122424 OK, sorry if my wording confused you. It's common to say that a morphism "coequalizes" two other morphisms without meaning that it's actually a coequalizer. But that language doesn't appear in the Adamek-Rosicky proof, and I was just explaining the argument they had already made. Is everything clear now?

Comment: Yes, it is clear now, except for the point why the canonical diagram of $B$ is filtered. But I've already found the place in the book where this is proved and I can read it.Thank you.

Comment: Actually, the proof on the page 22 [Proposition 1.22](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA22) in the book  that $\mathbb{Pres}_\lambda$ is $\lambda$-filtered is also a bit unclear to me: how did we use that ${\cal A} \downarrow K$ has less then $\lambda$ morphisms and the statement that it has a compatible cocone, e.g. a colimit of the forgetful functor $\cal D\to \cal K$ to see that every set of less then $\lambda$ morphisms has coequalizer?